# Display items on a listbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the list below to display the items on ranges D,E,F,G / N,O,P,Q / S,T,U,V ... and so on

The idea is to select the items that are on ranges: C2, H2, M2 ... etc. from a listbox and show their associated values on a second list:

[image]

[image]

I have used this code for the same purpose. The difference is that I had only two columns to display. I tried to edit my code to display all the data on the four columns:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim sCol!
    Dim Y%, X%
    ListBox2.Clear
    sCol = 3 + (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex * 2)

    With Worksheets("Cycle_Vie_M1")
        For X = 3 To .Cells(Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
            ListBox2.AddItem .Cells(X, sCol).Value
'            MsgBox .Cells(X, sCol).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 1) = .Cells(X, sCol + 1).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 2) = .Cells(X, sCol + 2).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 3) = .Cells(X, sCol + 3).Value
        Next X
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure your listbox columns count are set to 4

Comment: I made the changes, fixed the column numbers to 5, and made other changes, it's working thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's working, here's the right code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim sCol!
Dim Y%, X%
    ListBox2.Clear
    ListBox2.ColumnCount = 5
    sCol = 3 + (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex * 5)

    With Worksheets("Cycle_Vie_M1")

        For X = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
            ListBox2.AddItem .Cells(X, sCol).Value
'            MsgBox .Cells(X, sCol).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 1) = .Cells(X, sCol + 1).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 2) = .Cells(X, sCol + 2).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 3) = .Cells(X, sCol + 3).Value
            ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListCount - 1, 4) = .Cells(X, sCol + 4).Value
        Next X
    End With
End Sub
```